# Magento 2.1.6 - How to setup email templates header and footer

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates, header, 404-page, footer

I am new in Magento 2x. I just want to setup email header and footer globally.

I can't locate either header.html / footer.html files in my Magento file systems as well.

Also in "Marketing/Email Templates/Add New Template/" I select 'header' template from there and try to preview or save the new template the page reloads and shows this error message **"404 error: Page not found."** with this URL path

```
"/admin/admin/email_template/preview/key/198e5851939baf4c460d1b202e2ac643d1e26084bfd75982e1eb4553cedd3012/".
```

I will really appreciate if some one guides me to how to configure **header/footer** email templates and also help me to solve this 404 issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url which is loading for luma theme email header and footer template :

```
vendor/magento-email/view/frontend/email/header.html
vendor/magento-email/view/frontend/email/footer.html
```

copy here to paste with :

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Email/email/header.html
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Email/email/footer.html
```